# Should we edit the Candidates at standups question to make it more on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[Is it appropriate to bring candidates to your daily stand up?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/77233/16)

This question as it stands is answerable and ontopic and no more opinion based than any other question.  So IMO it could be reopened as is.  However I think a better question for the site is something like:

> How to best handle bringing a candidate into a stand-up meeting and what can
>   they get out of it?

However due to the fact that there are already 3 decent answers to the original question that would be invalidated by the new question.  I would also hate to see that new question I proposed here closed as a duplicate of the question linked which I feel is likely to happen.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question -- I wouldn't mind changing the question to the one you mentioned as I think its fair to assume whether a company chooses to do it as their own practice or not (that is probably the part where people think the question is "opinion based"). I'm already satisfied with the answers I've gotten.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it needs editing as it stands, and really I don't see why it was closed either, but then I rarely do.

The edit you propose would be better as a totally new question, and I also think it would be closed fairly quickly.

Answer (score -1):

No I don't think this is opinion based, however these in my opinion are Company regulations/specifics.

Why? What ever you do on an on-site interview will be depending on your Company different.

For example in my Company there is a Gallery of achievements, free meal(depending on time ofc), painting course ect.

Comment: The question is not what should my company do, but rather is it a good idea for any company to do it.